# Password resetting in laravel when email address is not unique

Tags: laravel, authentication

This might sound like an antipattern or a weak system design, but the client of my app has demanded that there can be multiple users with same email address.

So I added another unique column named `username` to the users table and removed `->unique()` constraint from `email` column.

Registration, Login are working fine but the problem arises during the password reset.

Consider the scenario:

> username - johndoe, email - john@example.com
>
> username - janedoe, email - john@example.com
>
> username - jimmydoe, email - john@example.com

If any one of them makes a request for a password reset link, they would have to use johndoe@example.com as their email. So which user's password is actually going to be reset when they click on reset link from mail? Turns out, the first user, in this case, johndoe. Even if the request was made by janedoe or jimmydoe.

So how do I reset password for a single username, rather than an email? What changes should I make in the ForgotPasswordController and/or ResetPasswordController controllers to solve this? Or, do I have to make changes in the core framework? If so, where and how?

Comment: What Laravel version is this? Do you use stock password reset flow?

Comment: When I think about your problem, I wonder more and more, where in the world do you live where people share email accounts. All sort of identity theft can be achieved by having access to someones email account.

Comment: @Kyslik Yes stock password reset flow. Only change I made is in users table by adding the username unique column. To answer your next question, I know it's super-weird :D but there's still a catch: although these accounts appear to be of different user, they aren't. All three accoutns will be accessed by the same human being who owns that email :-| So yeah, email account isn't being shared with others.

Comment: Do you have table `password_resets`? Inspect that and you will see that its using "email" field only. Other than that go and inspect `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider` to get knowledge about insights of the password flow.

Comment: You could modify forgot password module, they can enter username instead of email id to initiate the forgot password procedure

Comment: don't you have unique set on that column in your DB? You should

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tested in Laravel 5.3** [This answer modifies some core files(you may override it if capable) and it's not a clean solution.]

1. Ask user for the unique `username` value instead of `email` on **password forget form**.
2. Override the `sendResetLinkEmail()` method in `ForgotPasswordController.php` as folows. [Originally written in `SendsPasswordResetEmails.php`].

   ```
   public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
   {
       $this->validateEmail($request);

       $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
           $request->only('username')
       );

       return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                   ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                   : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
   }
   ```
3. you would also need to override the `validateEmail()` method.

   ```
   protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
   {
       $this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required']);
   }
   ```
4. Add `username` field instead of `email` on **password reset form**.
5. Override `rules()` in `ResetPasswordController.php` to over come the email field change.

   ```
    protected function rules()
       {
           return [
               'token' => 'required',
               'username' => 'required',
               'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
           ];
       }
   ```
6. Also override the `credentials()` in `ResetPasswordController.php`

   ```
   protected function credentials(Request $request)
       {
           return $request->only(
               'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
           );
       }
   ```
7. Update or override the `getEmailForPasswordReset()` method in `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword.php` to the folowing.

   ```
   public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
       {
           return $this->username;
       }
   ```

Laravel uses key-value pair to find the user and send email. If you pass `'username => 'xyz'` it will look for the first record with value `'xyz'` in `username` field.

Note: The unique column in users table is expected as `username`.
`Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword.php` is a trait, and I was not able to overide the `getEmailForPasswordReset` method, so i just modified the core file itself.

Comment: Where do I override the `getEmailForPasswordReset()` method?

Comment: `CanResetPassword` is an interface. One cannot simply define a method in an interface.

Comment: Never mind. There were two CanResetPassword files. Found the second one. And updated the method. It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword.php` is a trait, and I was not able to overide the `getEmailForPasswordReset` method, so i just modified the core file itself. If you are able or know then you may override it.  @Eisenheim glad to know it helped.

Comment: @iamab.in Did you get any workaround for how to override 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword.php' ?

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal, No. I haven't tried it after the answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

> This might sound like an antipattern or a weak system design, but the client of my app has demanded that there can be multiple users with same email address.

Then you need to rewrite this feature and ask user for some more unique information, no matter what it is going to be. Laravel provided password reset expects email to be unique and with your current design it won't work. There's no magic here. You you cannot disambiguate your user using non unique data.

Comment: The `username` is unique. Could that help in some way?

Comment: Since they all have the same email address in the reset link just ask for witch user. I guess it would be the same person with multiple accounts anyway. There is no other reason to have the same email. Apply the same solution everytime you encounter the issue.

Comment: Sure, if username is unique then ask for that instead of email. With minor tweaks you are good to go. Still I also see no point allowing multiple accounts with the same email address

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rework some things for this, but I feel like the user experience is better. Generate a unique key for each user (for data hiding). There is a helper method for creating unique keys.

Then, when the email is sent out, link the button to a route that utilizes this key.

Then, modify or create that route that points to the reset password controller. You would then know which user it was referring to.

Remove the need for the user to insert their password because you'd already know who it was.